# Cannot find TOCBLOCK, database may be corrupt

Tags: error-handling, database, logs

I opened Logs today and saw [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1F5T.png) which says: `ldm_parse_tocblock(): Cannot find TOCBLOCK, database may be corrupt.`

I am NOT dual-booting, my PC is running under Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS version, any thoughts?

Comment: Some details about how Ubuntu was installed might help. If you have any NTFS partitions — even with Windows removed — there can be consistency errors. Sometimes a `grub update` can fix this, though 

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @matigo I have 2 physical storage, 120GB SSD which is allocated solely for OS Ubuntu, and 1TB HDD.
My SSD doesn't have any NTFS partitions (https://imgur.com/a/9N6I8cf)
but HDD has, which I use only to store stuff. Would that somehow affect it?

Comment: @someone there's no notable changes or problems which made changes/lags on the operation. In fact, I am a newbie to whole Linux and installed Ubuntu not long ago and I found out about the TOCBLOCK when I was checking out the Logs - meaning it didn't pop up or anything like that till I opened the Logs app. Above I have tried to put it up as much as I could...